# Excel: how to return data of the last weekday?

Tags: excel-formula, weekday

```
| Column A | Column B |
| 14/4     | 1        |
| 15/4     | 100      |
| 16/4     | 70       |
| 17/4     | 80       |
```

What is the formula I could use to extract the data (column B) of previous weekday please?
So if I open the file on monday (17 april), formula should return 1. If I open the file on tuesday (18 apr), formula should return 80.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Column A also has the year?

Comment: Yep it also has year. So it should fully be 17/4/2023.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data in `A1:B6` use the formula `=XLOOKUP(WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1),$A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6)`

[image]

[WORKDAY](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/workday-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33)